# Python linprog minimization--simplex method

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, linear-algebra

I'm using scipy.optimize.linprog library to calculate the minimization using the simplex method. I'm working on this problem in my textbook and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction because I'm not getting the output I expect. The problem is:

```
Minimize          w = 10*y1 + 15*y2 + 25*y3
Subject to:       y1 + y2 + y3 >= 1000
                  y1 - 2*y2    >= 0
                            y3 >= 340
with              y1 >= 0, y2 >= 0
```

The code I wrote for this is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import linprog
A = np.array([
[1, 1, 1],
[1,-2, 0],
[0, 0, 1]])
b = np.array([1000,0,340])
c = np.array([-10,-15,-25])
res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b,
bounds=(0, None))
print('Optimal value:', res.fun, '\nX:', res.x)
```

Which gives the output:

```
Optimal value: -18400.0
X: [   0.  660.  340.]
```

I expect it to be:

```
Optimal value: -15100.0
X: [   660.  0.  340.]
```

I can't seem to find consistency with this function but maybe it's the way I'm using it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've set up the inputs slightly wrong; see [the manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-simplex.html). Specifically, you have a number of sign errors.

1. Your vector `c` has the wrong sign; `linprog` minimizes `c x` so `c` should just be the coefficients in `w = c x`
2. Your vector `b` and matrix `A` have the wrong sign. Their signs should be inverted to switch from your form of constraint `f(x) >= const` to the desired form for the `linprog` method, which is a less-than-or-equal, i.e. `-f(x) <= - const`
3. You are missing the final two constraints.
4. Your proposed minimum is < 0, which is obviously impossible as
   `w = 10*x1 + 15*x2 + 25*x3` is always positive with your constraints  as `x1,x2,x3>=0`.

The correct code reads:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

A = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1,2, 0], [0, 0, -1], [-1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0]])
b = np.array([-1000, 0, -340, 0, 0])
c = np.array([10,15,25])

res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b,bounds=(0, None))

print('Optimal value:', res.fun, '\nX:', res.x)
# python2
# ('Optimal value:', 15100.0, '\nX:', array([ 660.,    0.,  340.]))
# python3
# Optimal value: 15099.999961403426 
# X: [6.59999996e+02 1.00009440e-07 3.40000000e+02]
```

Comment: That's a great explanation--thank you!! I wish the documentation had more examples and was explained a bit better like this. I originally had vector c with the correct signs but switched them because I wasn't getting any output. As far as vector b and Matrix A are concerned, I should've know to invert the signs--more so, I should have realized all examples show less than or equal to and I needed to make that switch. I totally missed the final two constraints.

Comment: @R.Cox right, the print format seems slightly different in python2 vs. python3, but the result is the same, isn't it, up the above mentioned formatting difference?

Answer (score 1):

As the positiveness of y1 and y2 can be guaranteed under bounds=(0, None), a simplified version of code is shown as below:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

A = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1,2, 0], [0, 0, -1]])
b = np.array([-1000, 0, -340])
c = np.array([10,15,25])

res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b,bounds=(0, None))
print('Optimal value:', res.fun, '\nX:', res.x)
```

**Output:**

```
Optimal value: 15099.999961403195 

X: [6.59999996e+02 1.00009440e-07 3.40000000e+02]
```